# Wait until i get the complete message i am using reactive library to get the data

Tags: c#, string, multithreading, arrays, system.reactive

I am using reactive library I observe the bytes and when I get them I publish them. I am unable to find out where I should wait to collect all the bytes. and then process them.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
        { 
     public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                obj.SignatureAvailable.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Subscribe(HandlePinsAvailable);
            }

            void HandlePinsAvailable(byte[] signBytes)
            {
//here I will collect byte blocks.

                //MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(signBytes));
            }
    }

      public class SignatureListener
        {
             private Subject<byte[]> SignaturesAvailable = new Subject<byte[]>();

             public IObservable<byte[]> SignatureAvailable { get { return SignaturesAvailable.AsObservable(); } }

            private IDisposable SignatureSubscription;

            public SignatureListener()
            {
                SignatureSubscription = HidUtility.Messages.Subscribe(HandlePinMessageBytes);
            }
      public void HandlePinMessageBytes(byte[] signatureBytes)
            { 
    SignaturesAvailable.OnNext(sobj.RawData.ToArray());
    }
    public class data
    {
    public void get data()
    {
         private static Subject<byte[]> subject = new Subject<byte[]>();
      public static IObservable<byte[]> Messages { get { return subject.AsObservable(); } }
      subject.OnNext(bytes);//I have have the actuall blocks here.
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, so apologies if my answer is inappropriate.

I assume that what you have is a stream of Bytes that you are observing. This steam will 'chunk' bytes to you until you hit the end of the stream (like a `FileStream`).

If this is the case then you can just keep processing the bytes until the observable sequence completes.

```
var allBytes = new List<byte>();
org.SignatureAvailable.Subscribe(
    chunk=>{allBytes.AddRange(chunk);},       //OnNext
    ()=>{/*Do something with allBytes list*/} //OnCompleted
    );
```

The problem with this is that we have leaked this list out side of our asynchronous sequence. A better option maybe to use the `Aggregate` function

```
org.SignatureAvailable
   .Aggregate(new List<byte>(), (acc, chunk)=>acc.AddRange(chunk))
```

This will now return you a single `List<bytes>` contianing all the bytes once the `SignatureAvailable` sequence `OnCompletes`. To keep the format consistent, you probably want to return bytes. I think your solution would look something like the following:

```
org.SignatureAvailable
   .Aggregate(new List<byte>(), (acc, chunk)=>acc.AddRange(chunk))
   .Select(list=>list.ToArray())
   .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
   .Subscribe(HandlePinsAvailable);          //Will only get called once when the sequence completes will all bytes.
```

These links from my book may help:

Iterating over files:

http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#CreatingYourOwnIterator

Aggregating :

http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/07_Aggregation.html#BuildYourOwn